# Проверка event.target в обработке события

Tags: javascript

Есть некий контейнер:

```
var box = document.querySelector('.servises');
```

в нем ищу необходимые блоки и загоняю в массив:

```
var plates = [].slice.apply(box.querySelectorAll('.servises_content'));
```

Далее в цикле создаю объекты:

```
for(var i = 0; i < plates.length; i++) {
   plates[i] = new ServisePlate (plates[i], true);
}
```

Далее вешаю на контейнер событие на клик:

```
box.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.target .....) {

    }
});
```

Как мне проверить что клик произошел на ранее созданном объекте и вызвать его метод?

если сделать так:

```
box.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.target.classList.contains('servises_content')) {
       event.target = new ServisePlate (event.target);
       event.target.showBody();
    }else{
        var parent = event.target.parentElement;
        while (!parent.classList.contains('servises_content')) {
            parent = parent.parentElement;
            if(!parent) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        parent = new ServisePlate (parent);
        parent.showBody();
    }
});
```

то все работает, но меня смущает создание нового объекта при клике. По сути объекты то уже созданы ранее.......

Comment: А если добавить событий `click` не на контейнер, а на сами объекты `.servises_content`?

Comment: Думаю можно и так, но мне интересно как это будет выглядеть именно с событием на контейнере.

Comment: В таком случае, вам надо в массиве `plates` найти ваш объект, на котором произошло событие `click`. Допустим, у вас в объекте `ServisePlate ` хранится ссылка на **DOM** элемент в свойстве `srcElement`. Тогда надо сделать цикл по массиву и найти этот элемент `if(event.target==plates[i].srcElement)...`

Comment: Ага, спасибо за подсказку........ ссылка то была в конструкторе, только почему - то не додумался....

Comment: Бывает. Придет со временем. Если Вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос, то можете написать его и принять. Может, кому-то в будущем он пригодится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
box.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    plates.forEach(function(element, i) {
        if(event.target == plates[i].elem) {//проверяем что элемент события необходимый нам DOM элемент.
           plates[i].disclose();
        }else if(plates[i].elem.contains(event.target)){//Если нет, проверяем является ли он потомком с помощью стандартного метода  contains.
            plates[i].disclose();
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```